# iText: Generate a pdf file from html in a3

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I have this code and the conversion is working fine. But I can't set the page size to A3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File inputFile = new File("print_1.html");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(
            "xhtmlToPdf_holaMundo.pdf"));

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    renderer.layout();
    Document document = new Document();
    renderer.createPDF(os);

    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in css: `@page {  size: 8.5in 11in; }` OR you can use method `setPageSize()` on the document object.

http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_34

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a day.